# Using Char Array vs. std::string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, serial-port, ascii

I will be reading and writing data from [this](http://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/07scanner/download/products/urg-04lx/) laser detector.  The communication protocol involves all data being sent and received as sequences of ASCII characters (see the full specifications [here](http://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/07scanner/download/products/urg-04lx/data/URG_SCIP20.pdf)) In reading the data from the sensor, I will have to do a fair amount of work decoding sequences of these characters.

I know it is generally better to use std::string when dealing with strings, but with data such as this, is it better to stick with a basic array?

Comment: It depends, as usual ...

Comment: Note that `std::vector<char>` is also a "char array". As long as you don't use `new` nor `malloc`, you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

std::string is an abstraction over "basic arrays" doing all the dirty work. If you have to ask this question, then yes, you should use it.

Comment: And with `std::stringstream ss(std::string)` you can do the same things as reading from the file via `fstream`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an `std::queue<char>`.  Or possibly a `std::deque<char>`.

I am making this suggestion assuming that this is a "dumb" data buffer, between some kind of input FD and a class/entity that parses the data (implementing the specification you linked).

In that scenario, you will be pushing characters into one "side" of the queue as your device makes reading, and reading from the other side of the queue as your parser translates those characters into meaningful measurements.

This will be more efficient that using an `std::string`, if you find your program adds data to the front of the string.  Each time you insert at the *front* of a string, the class has to copy all the characters in the existing string into the space after the new data.